# Firemonkey Assign TPanel to TPanel doesnt work XE10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to use assign on a `TPanel` configured in the designer but it doesn't work.

```
var
  LPanel : TPanel;
begin
  LPanel := TPanel.Create(nil);
  LPanel.Assign(Panel1); // Panel1 is a panel made in the form designer
end;
```

The error message is something like "TPanel cannot be assigned to TPanel." (I have the german version of RAD Studio... The exact error message on german is "TPanel kann nicht zu TPanel zugewiesen werden.")

I designed a TPanel with other components in it using the Form Designer. Now I want to add new `TPanel` instances to a TLayout which should be the same as the TPanel I want to assign from, including all child controls.

Comment: 1) Please provide the _**full** and **precise**_ error message (Deutsch ist okay, wenn es noetig sind). There can be important clues in the message.  2) That said, I don't have access to Delphi to confirm: But it looks like this might be deliberately disabled for `TPanel`. So please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40558827/edit) to explain what you're trying to achieve/what your objective is. There may be a more appropriate way of solving your root problem.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I edited my answer :) Basiclly i want to to add TPanel's which are the same with all the childerns like my designed TPanel. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most VCL and FMX components, including `TPanel`, *DO NOT* implement `Assign()` at all.  Typically only utility classes that are used for component properties implement `Assign()` for use in their property setters.

For what you are attempting, you should use a Frame instead of `TPanel`.  You can design a Frame at design-time, just like a Form or DataModule, and then create instances of it at run-time as needed.

See Embarcadero's documentation for more details:

[Frames in FireMonkey](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Frames_in_FireMonkey)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't currently have access to Delphi to confirm. But it seems `Assign`ing `TPanel` is deliberately blocked by the framework.

That said, what you're trying to achieve seems more appropriately handled with [`TFrame`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TFrame)

Once you've created your frame, you should be able to use the following code to create a new instance at run-time.

```
uses
  ...
  frMyFrame;
...
var
  LNewFrame : TFrame;
begin
  LNewFrame := TMyFrame.Create(nil); //Are you sure you don't want to assign an owner?
  LNewFrame.Parent := Self; //Assuming you want to position the frame directly on the form
                            //Otherwise you could place it on a simple panel.
  //Set attributes for positioning
  //Don't forget resource management (see ownership comment)
  ...
end;
```